# How can Star Trek: Countdown ever be considered canon?

Tags: star-trek, canon, star-trek-data

I've just read this on the [Wikipedia article for spaceships named Enterprise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Starship_Enterprise):

> The main setting for the films Star
>   Trek: First Contact (1996), Star Trek:
>   Insurrection (1998), and Star Trek
>   Nemesis (2002).[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Starship_Enterprise)[6] According to
>   Star Trek: Countdown (2009), **Data
>   assumed command of the Enterprise
>   after Captain Picard retired** from
>   Starfleet to become the Ambassador to
>   Vulcan.

(emphasis added by me)

I haven't read *Star Trek: Countdown*, but looking at [its Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek:_Countdown) I read this:

> The comic came about because Anthony
>   Pascale, editor of TrekMovie.com, kept
>   requesting to the film's co-writer
>   Roberto Orci a way of having The Next
>   Generation characters "pass the baton"
>   back to the originals. When asked
>   whether the filmmakers' involvement in
>   the comic **made it canonical, Orci
>   stated he was in no position to
>   declare whether it was**, though he felt
>   it could easily remain as such unless
>   it was contradicted in a future
>   film.

(emphasis added by me)

How could that ever be canon if Data sacrifices himself during [Star Trek: Nemesis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek:_Nemesis) while saving Picard, still captain of the Enterprise?

> Data arrives with a single use personal transporter and has the captain beamed back to the Enterprise before ultimately **sacrificing himself** to shut down the weapon and destroy the ship.

Am I missing something? Was Data revived? Was Star Trek: Nemesis un-canonized? Was Data of Star Trek: Countdown really B4?

Comment: I think you answered your own question

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is non-canon (Memory-Alpha chooses [apocrypha](http://memory-alpha.org/wiki/B-4)):

> "The comic book series Star Trek:
>   Countdown (a tie-in to the 2009 Star
>   Trek  film) and the timeline
>   established for the Star Trek Online
>   game depict Data as alive in 2387.
>   Sometime prior, Geordi La Forge
>   installed Data's emotion chip into
>   B-4's neural net. This caused the
>   uploads to B-4 by Data to fully
>   reactivate, allowing Data's full
>   memory and personality to assert
>   itself, essentially resurrecting him.
>   Starfleet decided to reinstate the
>   android to service, and by the time of
>   Countdown Data had become captain of
>   the USS Enterprise-E."

This is expanded a bit in "[The Needs of the Many](http://memory-alpha.org/wiki/The_Needs_of_the_Many)", the Star Trek Online tie-in novel, and The Path to 2409 which is a timeline of events between "Nemesis" and the game.  It pegs [2385](http://web.archive.org/web/20100513160128/http://startrekonline.com/node/183/long) as the year Data was "Resurrected."

> "Chief Engineer Geordi La Forge
>   requests a long-term leave of absence
>   from Starfleet to work on personal
>   projects, including a plan to build
>   and test his own starship designs. But
>   his first project is to assist the
>   team at the Soong Foundation studying
>   the Soong-type android B-4. With his
>   help, on Stardate 62762.91 the team
>   unlocks what it calls the “Data
>   matrix,” successfully accessing the
>   personality, knowledge and memories of
>   Data, who had downloaded this
>   information into B-4 before his
>   destruction in the Battle of Bassen
>   Rift.
>
> The Data persona asserts itself over
>   B-4’s more primitive programming, and
>   the android is able to assist the
>   Soong Foundation team to upgrade the
>   positronic brain and recreate the
>   emotion chip invented by Dr. Noonien
>   Soong. The team is confident that
>   their work will be completed in
>   months. "

[2386](http://web.archive.org/web/20111213200957/http://www.startrekonline.com/node/216/long):

> "A surprise guest at the wedding of
>   Worf and Grilka is Data. With his
>   upgrades at the Soong Foundation
>   complete, Data requests that his
>   commission in Starfleet be
>   reactivated. While there are some
>   initial questions because the Data
>   persona is in the body once used by
>   B-4, after Jean-Luc Picard, William T.
>   Riker and several other current and
>   former members of the Enterprise crew
>   testify on Data's behalf, Starfleet
>   Command agrees to reinstate Data. He
>   is promoted to captain and assigned to
>   supervise the completion of the
>   Enterprise-E's refit."

This leads up to Countdown in 2387.  [Number Two](http://memory-alpha.org/wiki/Countdown,_Number_Two) features Data.

Of course, later Orci, when cornered by persistent Trekkies, [took the easy way out](http://trekmovie.com/2009/05/22/orci-and-kurtzman-reveal-star-trek-details-in-trekmovie-fan-qa/):

> "cugel the clever: In “Countdown”, the
>   Narada effortlessly destroyed an
>   armada of 24th century Klingon
>   warships and disabled the Enterprise-E
>   with one volley. However, in the film,
>   the Kelvin (and early 23rd century
>   ship) actually managed to exchange
>   fire and survive for at least several
>   minutes. It even managed to damage the
>   Narada by ramming it. Logically, this
>   makes no sense…. it should have been
>   destroyed immediately (and Kirk&mother
>   killed) given the firepower possessed
>   by the Narada. This is like the
>   Merrimac surviving a firefight with
>   the Bismark. Care to explain this
>   inconsistency?
>
> BobOrci: Easy. The comic is not
>   canon?"

Comment: My god...so the non-canon sources actually consider it a GOOD THING that B-4 was killed?  And Geordi was the murderer?  Talk about derailing a character - B-4 would (at that time) have been a unique person, with thoughts, experiences, and memories of his own...to think they could have NO ONE question his murder-by-overwriting is a gross disservice to the characters.

Comment: @Jeff - I read somewhere that Data objected to the process when he regained sentience, but I couldn't find a link or recall where.  References are deliberately vague.  The few times it's mentioned Data demurs when it's brought up (refers to it as his "Return" in Countdown).  The basic fanboy reasoning is B-4 is far less sophisticated and wasn't making progress as a sentient lifeform.  I believe it's moot canon-wise, Spiner has volunteered that he's too old to pick the role back up.

Comment: I agree it's a moot point, but I'm still appalled at the authors.  The vast lack of respect it demonstrates for the established characters is frightening :(

Comment: @Jeff Check out Daniel Perreira's answer.  They made a backup of B4 instead of straight up deleting him.  That makes it slightly better, but I'm surprised they didn't go whole-hog and just have Geordi build Data a new body.  That would avoid the ethical ickyness of stealing B4's body.

Comment: All of the events in *Star Trek Countdown* are contradicted in the non-canon story *Cold Equations: The Persistence of Memory*!  No offense intended to the answerer, just pointing this out.

Answer (score 9):

Geordi Leforge actually was against Data transferring over his memories to B-4, he concludes that B-4 will simply end up as a clone of Data. Later Picard and Data have a conversation about whether B-4 is simply a clone of Data now, and Data says that he is not SIMPLY because B-4 has no desire to better himself.

At the end of Nemesis Picard has a talk with B-4, where he explains that B-4 should better himself as Data had, and since Data's memories up to the point of the transfer is the same, you can say that Data himself had already begone the process of rebirth at that point. Data had also intended to never reactivate B-4, the entire point of Leforge giving B-4 the emotion chip, would in-fact have a profound impact on B-4 since he was still undergoing his "activation" as Data had mentioned was extremely hard for himself during the episode: [Eye of the Beholder](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Eye_of_the_Beholder_%28episode%29).

In a very strange way, you could say that this was like Data waking up from a coma. Remember, Data saving Lal's memories into him seemed like a way to preserve her forever for him, B-4 is Data now as much as the two Rikers were the same person. The difference, is Data died and made room for B-4 to replace him.

**This is also the rest of the story to how the Data matrix played out:** When Data first returned to consciousness, he refused to allow himself to exist at the expense of his brother's life. He therefore created a program in his mind to destroy his own consciousness before it destroyed B-4's. However, B-4 commandeered the program and, having heard that Data was crucial to the war with the Undine, deleted himself before Data could stop him. Data therefore survived in B-4's body.

Through this, Data was able to help the Soong Foundation in upgrading positronic brains and help in the recreation of the emotion chip originally developed by Doctor Soong. Ambassador Spock likened it to his resurrection a hundred and two years previously, though Data likened it more to a return. Meanwhile, a backup copy of B-4 was saved, and thus the science team hoped to create a "B-4 matrix", and possibly eventually bring Data's brother back to life in a new body.

Comment: Thanks for the rest of the story - which work was this in?  I remembered reading something like that, but I couldn't find it again.

Answer (score 4):

They did have his mentally challenged 'brother'. Remember he tried transferring some of himself to him - and at the end he starts whistling or whatever it was that he did that sort of hinted that maybe the transfer had some effect? Maybe they'll say he 'cloned' himself onto his 'brother'.

Or maybe they'll realize how bad that whole story was and just pretend it didn't happen :)

Comment: Yeah, that brother is B4. Data transfered his initial positronic configuration or something like that so that B4 would be able to evolve as much as Data (but never be Data).

Comment: Frankly I don't get the meme of ST:Nemesis being shitty. Maybe when it came around 2004 people had really enough of the whole story and characters and i can understand it. But well, I was watching it without even knowing people hate it so. Then I watched it again after a year. It's a great movie. Better and less naive than some other canon ST movies, IMO :)

Comment: I just think it's pretty stupid that they suddenly introduce a 2nd species of romulans that look very different from the 'regular' romulans. Romulans only split from vulcans a few hundred or thousand years ago. No even close to long enough for a 2nd species so vastly different to evolve. I also think the whole idea of using a clone of picard is pretty dumb, let alone this human clone convinces the other romulans to let him lead them AND they somehow manage to build some uber battle ship.

Comment: actually the idea of there being Remans was around before Nemesis (i don't have a quote). However, one could imagine that the Remans were natives of the star system the ex-vulcans settled in and were forced into being a labor class.

Comment: The film never explicitly states that Romulans and Remans are related. @Xantec You are mistaken, the first mention of Remans was in Nemesis.

Comment: @brian : No, the first mention of Remans is in the Star Fleet Universe... As a socio-cultural divide in the Romulans, where the two "capital" planets are Romulus and Remus. (Fed "capitals" include Earth, Vulcan, Andor, and Tellar)  Given that the maps were codified for the SFU well before the 1987 release of **Federation and Empire**; it was closely related to the 1981 boardgame **Federation Space**'s map, which also has Romulus and Remus as the two capital hexes. So Remans are not "new" to the overall Trek fandom, just to canon.

Comment: @aramis: Sure, Romulus and Remus are capitols.  But was the existence of a Reman race documented at that time, or just the existence of two capitol planets?

Comment: Not as a separate biological race, only as a separate subculture.

Comment: Ignoring if they mentioned them before or not - how plausible is it that they would make a clone of picard, and then deciding they couldn't use him anymore, that they wouldn't just kill him? And then how plausible is it that a human would be able to convince this other race/subculture that he should lead them? And then how plausible is it that this other race living as slave labor would some how be able to build the most powerful spaceship anyone has seen?